# Can't upload to wordpress from home connection?

Tags: networking

I have this really strange issue. I have multiple wordpress blogs, all on unrelated hostings (hostgator, and GCP).

I'm not able to upload images bigger than like 500kb to any blog through the interface or rest API from my home connection.

Some of my coworkers can upload fine from their home. And I can upload fine from a server.

So I know the issue is not my wordpress sites, it is my home connection. Yet I literally never had a problem with any other sites I've used for years. Not a single issue. Except for this wordpress problem, which has been going on for as long as I've had this internet connection.

How can I debug / fix the issue? Through Chrome, in the dev tool network, the request `wp-admin/async-upload.php` just stalls. No response, no error, no bytes transfered. Through the rest API in node.js I get either `write EPIPE` or `read ECONNRESET`

Comment: Try different browsers?

Comment: 1. Try starting an Incognito session (`ctrl + shift + N`) in case it's something in your browser's session, cache, or plugins causing the problem. 2. Do you have the same problem with Firefox, Safari, or edge? 3. Do you have the same problem on your home network on a different computer?